# Machine learning with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am making a music player site with nodeJS. I am trying to make a music recommendation system. I store the music related information in the database in the format:

song_index(int), song_name(string) , song_thumbnail(string) , artists_name(string) , song_filename(string) , likes(int) , song_language(string) , song_genre(string)

I need to recommend the music based on language,genre,likes and on user's old searches. Is it good if I use machine learning libraries in javascript(like tensorflow) or use python from nodeJS(using process method).

I haven't used any ML libraries till now and it would be helpful if you place the sample codes for the explanation.

Comment: I dont know if you need machine learning in order to make those kind of recomendations. Maybe you could just store how many times the user listen to a song that has some kind of tags, next just suggest any random song that has the same tags that the user click the most. But... that is just what I would do in order to save time and computer power.
If you want to continue researching by your own, I can suggest you to check the following links: 
* http://jamesthom.as/blog/2018/08/07/machine-learning-in-node-dot-js-with-tensorflow-dot-js/ 
* https://www.tensorflow.org/js

Comment: Please understand the scope of what you want and then select tech , please just dont pick what is trending  case in point ML and apply it incorrectly . since such can be achieved with dataset and tuned sql queries ! :)

Comment: Also, you can check this youtube videos that are super didactic:
This is a Coding-Train's playlist about tensorflow js: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bmMRCIoTi72aNWHo7epX4L
This is a FreeCodeCamp.org tutorial about deep learning and neural networks 
in tensorflowJS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoYfa6mYOG4